# How to empty all the queues in Nifi at a time?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have started exploring NiFi. I have built some flow which is working. But i want to clear all the queues at a time to test the flow each time if i made any changes. I know we can stop and start each processor and test step by step. But i want to know is there a way we can clear all the queues at a time.

Answer (score 4):

the easiest way to stop nifi, delete the following folders, and start it again:

- content_repository
- database_repository
- flowfile_repository
- provenance_repository

another approach to use [nifi-api](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/) to get list of all queues and then call function to empty them.

Comment: Hi Daggett, thanks for your answer. Can you littlebit elaborate how to do in both the ways. What are the exact steps to do them.